# Dividends and tax withholding for ETF vs Mutual Fund for U.S. Non-Resident Alien?

Tags: united-states, mutual-funds, etf, dividends, non-resident

I'm a non-US resident alien, considering to invest in either commission-free ETFs and Mutual Funds offered by TD Ameritrade.

According to The American Jobs Creation Act of 2004, certain type of dividends from dividends are exempted from the 30% tax withholding. Does this apply to ETFs as well?

Comment: Non resident as in "I don't have a green card, but I'm on H1/L1 status" or "non resident for tax purposes because I'm a tourist/student/not in the US"?

Comment: I'm not in the US (and never been).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does my prior answer here to a slightly different question help at all?

[Are there capital gains taxes or dividend taxes if I invest in the U.S. stock market from outside of the country?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/4939/are-there-capital-gains-taxes-or-dividend-taxes-if-i-invest-in-the-u-s-stock-mar/5100#5100)

Comment: Been away for quite some time. But yeah the link is very informative.Thanks :)

Comment: From IRS perspective ETF is treated as mutual fund it seems.