# Foreigner trading stocks through US brokerage bank

Tags: stocks, brokerage, online-brokerage

I am a foreigner currently living in the US, and I have a SSN due to my employment here. However, I will be returning to my home country next year. My question is: since I have an SSN, I am able to open a brokerage account at a US brokerage bank; then, if i return to my home country (say, permanently), but trade stocks through my US brokerage account and make a profit, what are my tax responsibilities? To which government do I pay taxes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are non-US citizens trading on US stocks/options subject to tax?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/28879/are-non-us-citizens-trading-on-us-stocks-options-subject-to-tax)

Comment: The fact that you are "living in the US" right now has little to do with the future "when you return to home country". Most nonresident alien can open brokerage account **remotely** in the US, with or without SSN/ITIN.