# What are the stock fees charged on nonresidents?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stock-markets, non-resident, fees

When a foreigner invests in the US stock market, are the dividends taxed at 37%? What if the stock does not pay a dividend? Will foreigners be charged anything if the stock does not pay a dividend? Is there a fee for buying and selling US stocks?

Comment: Where did you get the 37% figure?

Comment: Regarding the "fee for buying and selling US stocks": are you referring to capital gains tax or stockbroker commissions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are non-US citizens trading on US stocks/options subject to tax?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/28879/are-non-us-citizens-trading-on-us-stocks-options-subject-to-tax)